# Per metum pergendum - Move forward despite fear

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, motto

I'm looking for a translation for a motivational phrase with a meaning like:

- To do something despite of doubt.
- To go on in the presence of worries.
- To act even if there are fears.

I'm open to similar meanings, if the result sounds nice.

Do you think "**Per metum pergendum**" will work/how bad is it?

Answer (score 4):

I would personally go with something like *etsi metuas, prodi* ("Even if you're afraid, proceed"), or if you want it to sound more like a motto, *metuens sed tamen prodiens* ("Afraid but still going forward") — which even has nice rhythm if you disregard the exact vowel lengths.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a nice answer and I look forward to seeing more from you.